Sign discrepancy in covariant derivative
Suppose that $E\rightarrow M$ is a vector bundle over a differentiable manifold, equiped with a connection $\nabla$. The connection $\nabla$ induces connections on the various vector bundles constructed from $E$ (e.g $E^{\ast} $, $\text{End}(E)$, etc.) and covariant derivatives on the corresponding vector bundle-valued forms ($\Omega^{\ast}(E)$, $\Omega^{\ast} (E^{\ast} ) $, $\Omega^{\ast} (\text{End}(E)) $, etc.). I will denote by $d^{\nabla}$ all these covariant derivatives.
There are pairings, denoted by $\wedge$, between forms
$$\Omega^{\ast}(M)\wedge\Omega^{\ast}(E)\rightarrow\Omega^{\ast}(E),$$
$$\Omega^{\ast}(\text{End}(E))\wedge\Omega^{\ast}(E)\rightarrow\Omega^{\ast}(E),$$
$$\Omega^{\ast}(\text{End}(E))\wedge\Omega^{\ast}(\text{End}(E))\rightarrow\Omega^{\ast}(\text{End}(E)).$$
defined in a natural way using the wedge product on $\Omega^{\ast}(M)$. We can verify the graded Leibniz rule for $d^{\nabla}$ with respect to $\wedge$ in the above pairings:
$$d^{\nabla}(\omega\wedge\eta)=d^{\nabla}\omega\wedge\eta+(-1)^{deg(\omega)}\omega\wedge d^{\nabla}\eta.$$
Now, suppose that $E\rightarrow M$ is a trivial vector bundle. Any connection on $E$ can be written in the form $\nabla=d+A$, where $d$ is the standard flat connection and $A$ is an $\text{End}(E)$-valued 1-form. We can verify the following formulas for the covariant derivatives:
$$d^{\nabla}\omega=d\omega+A\wedge\omega\quad\text{if }\omega\in\Omega^{\ast}(E),$$
$$d^{\nabla}\eta=d\eta+[A,\eta]\quad\text{if }\eta\in\Omega^{\ast}(\text{End}(E)).$$
Here $[,]$ denotes the graded commutator.
Lets go to the point. We can compute, for $\omega\in\Omega^{\ast}(E)$, the derivative $d^{\nabla}(A\wedge\omega)$ in two different ways. First, we can do what follows:
$$d^{\nabla}(A\wedge\omega)=d(A\wedge\omega)+A\wedge(A\wedge\omega).$$
But, we can also do:
$$
d^{\nabla}(A\wedge\omega)=d^{\nabla}A\wedge\omega-A\wedge d^{\nabla}\omega=dA\wedge\omega-A\wedge(d\omega+A\wedge\omega)=$$
$$\phantom{d^{\nabla}(A\wedge\omega)}=dA\wedge\omega-A\wedge d\omega-A\wedge(A\wedge\omega)=d(A\wedge\omega)-A\wedge(A\wedge\omega).$$
where I have use that $d^{\nabla}A=dA+[A,A]=dA$.
My question is, why did I get such a discrepancy of signs between these two calculations? I have checked all the formulas and have not found the error.

For $\eta\in\Omega^k(\mathrm{End}(E))$ and $\mu\in\Omega^l(\mathrm{End}(E))$ the form $[\eta,\mu]\in\Omega^{k+l}(\mathrm{End}(E))$ is defined by
$$
[\eta,\mu](X_1,\dots,X_{k+l})=\frac1{k!l!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+l}}\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)[\eta(X_{\sigma_1},\dots,X_{\sigma_k}),\mu(X_{\sigma_{k+1}},\dots,X_{\sigma_{k+l}})]
$$
The mistake now is $[A,A]=0$. Instead it is true that $[A,A]=2\,A\wedge A$. This means that in your second approach you have to add the term $2(A\wedge A)\wedge\omega=2\,A\wedge (A\wedge\omega)$, which then gives the correct result.

Let me also say that in the whole discussion it is not important that $E$ is a trivial vector bundle. In general, two connections on $E$ are related by $\tilde\nabla=\nabla+A$ where $A$ is an $\text{End}(E)$-valued 1-form and for $\omega\in\Omega^*(E)$
$$
d^\tilde\nabla\omega=d^\nabla\omega+A\wedge\omega
$$
Now the induced connections on $\text{End}(E)$ are related by $\tilde\nabla=\nabla+\mathrm{ad}(A)$, where
$$
\mathrm{ad}:\mathrm{End}(E)\to\mathrm{End}(\mathrm{End}(E))
$$
is the vector bundle homomorphism defined by $\mathrm{ad}(B)(C):=BC-CB$. For endomorphism bundle valued forms one has $\mathrm{ad}(\eta)\wedge\mu=[\eta,\mu]$ and therefore indeed
$$
d^\tilde\nabla\eta=d^\nabla\eta+\mathrm{ad}(A)\wedge\eta=d^\nabla\eta+[A,\eta]
$$

Thank you very much, I knew it was some stupid mistake like that. About your second comment, I know that the triviality of the the vector bundle plays no role in this calculation, but it seems to be essential in Chern-Simons Theory.
